# Doctrine Yaml Mapping Shared Columns

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, yaml

Is it possible using Yaml orm files to specify a base Entity that all of the Entities will share, I can compare this to C# ADO.NET where you can specify a class that holds all of the data that will be common among all of your tables

For example, say I have the below YAML mapping for Doctrine:

```
src\SITEBUNDLE\Entity\User:
    REALTYBLOG\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    id:
        id:
            type:integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
        fields:
            firstName:
                type: string
                length: 255
           lastName:
                type: string
                length: 255
            middleInital:
                type: string
                length: 1
            username:
                type:
                length: 26
            passwordHash:
                type: string
                length: 255
           createdOn:
                type: dateTime
           createdBy:
                type: string
                length: 26
           modifiedOn:
                type: dateTime
           modifiedBy:
                type: string
           deletedOn:
                type: dateTime
```

Now lets say that I have created multiple other YAML configs and all of them share the createdOn, createdBy, modifiedOn, modifiedBy, deletedOn columns. Can I specify an overlaying orm file that I can include in all of my orm files so I don't have to redundantly add them to every orm file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. It's quite simple.

```
TextItem:
  columns:
    topic: string(255)

Comment:
  inheritance:
    extends: TextItem
    type: concrete
    columns:
     content: string(300)
```

More information: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/yaml-schema-files.html -> inheritance / simple inheritance